# population of bacteria

Tags: expected-value

> The population of bacteria changes every minute by 5% up or down with equal likelihood. What is expected bacteria size after 50 min?

My approach: I figured out that it can't be 0, since the amount of increase/decrease is not same, it is percentage. But then how to do it, I have no idea.

Comment: What's the expected size after $1$ minute?  What about $2$ minutes?

Comment: ah, it remains same